# ERROR 002760: This service definition file was created for a hosted layer and must be uploaded directly to a portal using the portal website or ArcMap

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-portal

ERROR 002760: This service definition file was created for a hosted layer and must be uploaded directly to a portal using the portal website or ArcMap.
Failed to execute (UploadServiceDefinition).

I am getting the above error when I am trying to publish a mxd to a portal as a feature service

```
import arcpy, os

# define local variables
wrkspc = 'C:/Ronit/Projects/DU/Hosted/'
path2MXD = r"C:\Ronit\Projects\DU\Hosted\temp.mxd"
mapDoc = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(path2MXD)

con = 'GIS Servers/connection.ags

service = 'DemoHost'
sddraft = wrkspc + service + '.sddraft'
sd = wrkspc + service + '.sd'
summary = 'Population Density by County'
tags = 'county, counties, population, density, census'

arcpy.SignInToPortal_server("username", "password", "")

# create service definition draft
analysis = arcpy.mapping.CreateMapSDDraft(mapDoc, sddraft, service, 'MY_HOSTED_SERVICES', "", "", None, summary, tags)

# stage and upload the service if the sddraft analysis did not contain errors
if analysis['errors'] == {}:
    # Execute StageService
    arcpy.StageService_server(sddraft, sd)
    # Execute UploadServiceDefinition
    arcpy.UploadServiceDefinition_server(sd, con)
else:
    # if the sddraft analysis contained errors, display them
    print analysis['errors']

os.remove(sd)

"""
```

Comment: I know that there is a script example somewhere in the ArcGIS Portal documentation which shows how to upload a hosted service definition file, I will endevour to find the link and post it here for you.

Comment: Found it. https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.5/analyze/arcpy-mapping/createmapsddraft.htm#     its for ArcGIS ArcMap 10.5, and there is also a modify SD fil section also.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that you are using ArcGIS server scripting when in the error it is telling you that the .sd file that was created is meant to be published through portal. See below:

002760: This service definition file was created for a hosted layer and must be uploaded directly to a portal using the portal website or ArcMap .

Description
The service definition file was created for a hosted layer on an (ArcGIS Online or ArcGIS Enterprise) portal. It cannot be uploaded to ArcGIS Server.

Solution
Either upload your service definition file directly to a portal using the portal website or ArcMap, or create a service definition file for ArcGIS Server and upload it directly to an ArcGIS Server site through ArcGIS Server Manager or ArcMap.

In your code you log into Portal. If this was by mistake then take that code out. But this code:

```
if analysis['errors'] == {}:
    # Execute StageService
    arcpy.StageService_server(sddraft, sd)
    # Execute UploadServiceDefinition
    arcpy.UploadServiceDefinition_server(sd, con)
else:
    # if the sddraft analysis contained errors, display them
    print analysis['errors']

os.remove(sd)
```

Is specifically to take an .sd analyze it, and then publish to the localhost ArcGIS server, not portal.